# What pattern to use to separate an objects creation from it's class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Assume I have a Class Foo which has many internal variables, only one constructor and non modifying methods.
The calculation of the values for the internal variables involves state variables and complex functions and thus should not be part of Foo. Thus I created a class FooCreator that performs the calculus and in the end creates Foo.

First I implemented all member variables necessary for the creation of Foo  separately in FooCreator and added a createFoo() function, but in the end FooCreator became almost a copy of Foo plus some more state variables.

Next I decided to let FooCreator inherit from Foo which saves a lot of typing but
this just does not feel like a clean solution, since to gain sth. I have to make Foo's member variables protected instead of private, thus exposing more than I want for other users. Foo should not be used as base class except for the creation.

I had a look at the factory pattern but that seems overkill as well as the builder.
Surely this problem will be very common. So what would be the proper way to deal with this problem?

Some code example would look like this:

```
class Foo{
    private: //protected for second case
      int mVal;
      State mState;
      ComplexStuff mStuff;
      //...

    public:
      Foo():mVal(),mState(),mStuff(){}
      Foo(int val, State const& state, ComplexStuff const& stuff):
        mVal(val),mState(state),mStuff(stuff){}
      bool loadFromFile();

      bool evalStateTransition(State const& formerState) const{/*....*/}
      bool someTest(int) const{/*....*/};
      GraphicItem* visualize() const{/* ....*/};
      //...  
  };

  class FooCreator{  
    private:
      int mVal;
      State mState;
      ComplexStuff mStuff;

      StuffVisualizer mStuffVis;
      Paramset mParams;    
      //...

    public:
      FooCreator(Paramset const& set):
        mVal(),mState(),mStuff(),mStuffVis(),mParams(set){}
      constructState(int, int, int);
      gatherStuff1(File file1);
      Foo createFoo();

      int evalStateTransition(State const& formerState)  const{
        /*same long code as in Foo*/
      }
      bool someTest(int) const{ /*same long code as in Foo*/}
      GraphicItem* visualize() const{ /*same long code as in Foo*/}
      //...  
  };

  class FooCreator2 : public Foo{  
    private:
      StuffVisualizer mStuffVis;
      Paramset mParams;    
      //...

    public:
      FooCreator(Paramset const& set):Foo(),mParams(set){}
      constructState(int, int, int);
      gatherStuff1(File file1);
      Foo createFoo();    
  };
```

Comment: You had it right, the factory pattern fits this scenario.

Comment: @jli: True I want to separate creation from the created object, but I need only one creation process not different creators. Further I need access to many of Foo's functions as well. Should I copy all methods in the creator ? I cannot create Foo to use its methods as long as it is not complete.

Comment: If all `Foo` objects need to do some complex calculations in order to by considered complete, why shouldn't that stuff be done in the constructor?  The factory pattern is useful when you want to initialize a Factory that can spit out any number of objects all with the same initial state.

Comment: @Michael: Foo is part of a library and only initialized from a file. I use another program to build Foo objects and then write them to the file. Users of Foo are not supposed to build Foo without the file.

Comment: @Martin - I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.  Why would `Foo` being compiled into a library matter?  What do you mean by "initialized from a file"?

Comment: @Michael: sorry for being vague: I extract information from an image and use this information to construct another data format (the foo in the example). The  extractor needs several libraries. In the end it creates a foo and saves it's representation to a file. Users of the new format only read from the file, they ignore the image extraction. Hence I separate the extraction from the data and keep it in another class FooCreator. Here I need many methods from Foo in the public interface so the Question boils down to rewriting all those methods or inheriting from Foo. I finally chose the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write `friend class FooCreator;` in Foo, and now you can access all the private fields of Foo from FooCreator. Then just create a field of type Foo in FooCreator... Nice, and easy.

Comment: But then I have to include FooCreator in Foo and this days a lot of things into a formerly small and well defined library containing Foo

Comment: Oops that was wrong I had a namespace issue the friend itself does not need an include, as you say friend would work and could help in my scenario.

Answer (score 3):

[It can be good to keep complex logic out of the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621800/business-logic-in-constructors-a-good-idea).  However, if you don't want to use the **Factory** or **Builder** pattern, then you can extract a [ParameterObject](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject).

If you need to use methods in `Foo` to create an instance then maybe you should try to split `Foo` into two classes.

Comment: “It is good to keep complex logic out of the constructor” – and I’m not **at all** convinced by that. The constructor should ensure that the object is in a valid, meaningful state. If that involves complex logic, so be it (see file streams). A constructor doesn’t define itself by the amount of logic it handles, only by the effect: leave the object in a well-defined state.

Comment: This is just a design principle I follow.  Certainly it is more important to leave the object in a well-defined state (a good way to do this is to keep your constructor simple).  [Also, it helps for testability and managing dependencies.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621800/business-logic-in-constructors-a-good-idea)

Comment: @GarrettHall - Why would it be good to keep complex logic out of the constructor?  There are times when moving stuff out of the constructor makes great sense, but I don't think that complexity is a good enough reason by itself.  After all, that complexity is going to have to go somewhere!

Comment: @Garrett I’m not convinced by most of what Uncle Bob writes. With regard to constructors we had a similar thread (C++) coming to the opposite conclusion here. Of course I don’t find it now … I agree that in any case it’s a trade-off but Uncle Bob’s flat-out assertion at the beginning of his answer is just too general, and generally wrong.

Comment: @GarrettHall - There's a big difference between business logic and state necessary for an object to be considered complete.  In other words, if a class's constructor is calling methods on other objects, it better be to complete the state of **this** object.  That doesn't appear to be the situation here.

Comment: I don't believe logic should **never** go in constructors.  However, when unit **testing**, it helps a great deal if I can inject dependencies without worrying how the creational logic is going to use them.  Plus doing your creational logic outside gives you more **extensibility** in terms of what you pass in.  But this is just a rule of thumb for me, I still break it depending on the context.

Comment: Concerning my example: I construct the object in it's proper constructor but I need a lot of states to gather the necessary data for the final construction. I want to keep the construction process out of the class. It's not about logic inside the constructor. That one is complete. It's the creation process that bothers me and it's interaction with he created object.

Comment: Well, if a function gets big enough, you can allways find parts, repeated, witch sould be given a function. The problem with C++ objects, that you sometimes don't wan't to expose the dirty helper function in the class declaraion (like "friend void make_sure_things_are_rigth_in_threre(X);") in the class header, but you need them to access private data. I think it's great that C++11 has lamdas... I'll use them a lot