# Is it ok to combine friendship with inheritance to access private data members

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation, friend

Let's assume I want a single class Child and only this class to inherit from Father
and grant Child access to Fathers data members. Apart from this no one should inherit from father to get to its internals, hence I keep the data of Father private

Edit: I opted against protected since I want the data hidden. Some people advocate this as good practice but perhaps its a little too dogmatic: (e.g. Herb Sutter in http://drdobbs.com/184403867) Actually the class should be extended only once. Hence prohibiting inheritance as Steve Jessop pointed out would be an option but I think the cost of that (virtual etc.) is going too far for what I need.

Code would look like this:

```
class Father{
  friend class Child;
  public: 
    //functions
  private:
    int mData;
}

class Child: public Father{
  public:
    void changeData(int val){mData=val;}
}
```

Am I running into some serious trouble here or is this a valid decision assuming that inheritance was a good decision in the first place.

Comment: How about making mData `protected`, if you really need direct access to it?

Comment: It smells, but it *could* be a good idea. After all, CRTP is a use case of this pattern (private destructor + friend child). We definitely need more context to tell.

Comment: Why don't you just move `changeData` to `Father` and make `mData` private to `Father`? If `Child` accesses mData directly, you're breaking encapsulation.

Comment: The question is do you really want/need inheritance or are you only using inheritance for the purpose shown here?  As you've done it, it will get you what you want, only Child will have access to Father's data.  But another approach would be to have a private member in Father which you could access from the Child class (still as a friend) and then wouldn't need inheritance.  So I think you could do the above with or without inheritance.  Also, does friend apply to classes derived from Child?  I can't recall atm.

Comment: @Nedtron no friends do not inherit

Comment: @Alexandre: I know it smells ;-) The purpose is a factory/creator as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231955/what-pattern-to-use-to-separate-an-objects-creation-from-its-class. I need several functions of Father in the Child Class. The child class is the creator for the father class (... from a human perspective THAT sounds WEIRD ;-) The creator must exactly mimick the father and add some state from the creation

Comment: ok, then I think you could accomplish what you need with or without inheritence.  you said the child needs several functions of Father which inheritance would provide.  could these be public, in which case child could just use father by composition not inheritance?  or are these methods only allowed to be used from Child?  even if so, you could still have private methods and data members in father and friend child and still not use inheritance.  use inheritance if Child "is-a" Father.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't actually prevent anyone else using `Father` as a base class, it just prevents them from accessing `mData` if they do.

If that's what you want (`Child` has privileged access to `Father`, that other classes don't have, and the fact that `Child` happens to also have a base class `Father` is unrelated), fine.

If you additionally forbid anyone else from using `Father` as a base class (either via documentation alone, or using the trick with the virtual base class), then the use of `friend` becomes a bit pointless. You might as well just make `mData` protected instead of private, that's exactly what protected is for.

Answer (score 1):

`protected:` access specifier is introduced for exactly the same purpose.

Though this will grant member access to **all the** `Child` of `Father`, this design is cleaner and more maintainable at long run.

Comment: I answered much the same but then realised that the OP seems to want ONLY the child class to have access to mData, while using protected lets any class that inherits from Father access it.

Comment: @DavidHall, yes I am aware of that. However, for maintainability and good coding practice, making members `protected` is more desirable.

Comment: @iammilind: I thought private is often more sensible than protected since one should in general not use inheritance to get access to the base class data but to make the new class accessible via the same interface. Hence inherit mostly from abstract classes to use polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

if `Child` is the only class that should inherit `Father`, then you could declare those members and methods in `Father` that you want to be transfered over to `Child` (but that you still want to keep "secret" from other classes) protected instead of private.

just like private, protected is not accessible from outside.

as opposed to private, protected is inherited.