# Complicated initialization in constructor

Tags: java, oop

I have a sort of model that manages maps of varying data.  I've read that constructors should not contain business logic, but I've also read that constructors are free to do what they need to do to initialize the state of the object.  What if, given map A and map B in the constructor, I want to merge those two maps and set the result in a third field.  Maybe I also want to do some cleanup or something.  Is this bad practice?  If so, why?

```
public class MapManager {

    private Map<String, Object> mapA;
    private Map<String, Object> mapB;
    private Map<String, Object> combinedMap;

    public MapManager(Map<String, Object> mapA, Map<String, Object> mapB) {
        this.mapA = mapA;
        this.mapB = mapB;
        this.combinedMaps = initCombinedMap(mapA, mapB);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMapA() {
        return mapA;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMapB() {
        return mapB;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getCombinedMap() {
        return combinedMap;
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> initCombinedMap(Map<String, Object> mapA, Map<String, Object> mapB) {
        Map<String, Object> combinedMap = new HashMap<>(mapA);

        if (mapB != null) {
            mapB.forEach(combinedMap::putIfAbsent);
        }

        return combinedMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is business logic in constructors a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621800/is-business-logic-in-constructors-a-good-idea)

Comment: You have a typo in `public Map<String, Object> getCombinedMap()` method, it is referencing `combinedMap` instead of `combinedMaps`.

Comment: `initCombineMap` should not be static

Comment: @Eehol How is this question a duplicate of the question you provided in the flag? They are asking specific questions, the only connection is that they both mention *business logic*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read that constructors should not contain business logic, but I've also read that constructors are free to do what they need to do to initialize the state of the object.

Both of these statements are good advice — and they're not in contradiction.

I think that your question is really about what counts as "business logic". The general idea is that "business logic" implements "business rules", meaning behaviors that the actual "business client" of the software (not a developer) has asked for, or might care about.

---

For example, suppose a business rule says that Cyrillic letters are allowed in usernames, *unless* either (1) the username also includes Latin letters, or (2) every Cyrillic letter in the username is one that is easily mistaken for a Latin counterpart. (This business rule helps prevent spoofing: I can't impersonate an account named 'Ben' by creating one named 'Веn', nor one named 'Дима' by creating one named 'Димa'.)

Now, you presumably have a business domain object class, called something like `User`, that represents an application user; so you might be tempted to implement this business rule as an invariant of the `User` class, meaning that it's literally impossible to have an instance of `User` that violates this business rule. To that end, you implement this rule in the constructor (probably by delegating to some sort of `validateUsername` method or something).

One problem with this is that it's not literally impossible to have a user with a username that violates this rule; if an important customer calls up to demand the username [сор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80), then someone might need to go into the database and manually create that user — in which case you don't want the `User` class to blow up the first time you try to load that user from the database.

Another problem with this is that as the rule becomes more complicated over time, you may end up extracting the relevant data into a database or configuration store, and you obviously don't want to need a database connection just to instantiate `User` in a unit-test.

So a better approach is to distinguish between the *technical restrictions on the `User` class* — e.g. the fields that must be populated or else things will blow up, the fields that must not be mutated or else things will blow up — and the *business restrictions on user accounts*. The class itself should strictly enforce the former, but not the latter. Instead, you should have a separate method for validating users, and call that method before adding a user to the database.

---

Unfortunately, I don't understand your `MapManager` class well enough to comment on it (and I'm actually a little bit skeptical that it makes sense as a [cohesive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) class), but if it helps, here are some examples of initialization logic that are *not* considered "business logic":

- If the class represents a data structure, such as a doubly linked list (`java.util.LinkedList`), a hash table (`java.util.HashMap`), a red-black tree (`java.util.TreeMap` or `java.util.TreeSet`), then it's absolutely expected that its constructors will include logic to initialize the data structure — especially if it has a constructor that takes an existing collection and copies its contents (as those examples all do). This is not "business logic", because the business clients have no opinion about them; they probably don't even know the terms "linked list" and "tree". *Everything* about these classes falls in the category of "technical" rather than "business".
- If the class has an immutable field that's not supposed to be null, then it's absolutely expected that its constructor will check for this and raise a `java.lang.NullPointerException` with an informative message. Here there may be some influence of a business rule on a technical implementation — we can imagine a new business requirement that translates fairly directly to "this field will have to be nullable now" (though in fact that might get implemented a different way, e.g. by changing the field to a `java.util.Optional`) — but it's a technical rule because there's likely to be downstream code that relies on it, e.g. writing things like `this.username.toLowerCase()` without checking for null. (This is a matter of pragmatism; why write extra code to support null usernames if they're unlikely to ever be allowed? Better to just validate upfront.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine but depending on what you are using this for it might be a bit over-complicated. For example if the only time you are combining `Map A` and `Map B` is in the constructor then you should remove the `initCombinedMap` method and do the combining in the actual constructor.

You can also use `Pair` from `javafx.util` package to have a container for your maps. Then your getters could get retrieve the `Key` for `mapA` and `Value` for `mapB` from the pair.

This is how your class would look after implementing these suggestions:

```
public class MapManager {

    private Pair<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>> maps;
    private Map<String, Object> combinedMaps;

    public MapManager(Map<String, Object> mapA, Map<String, Object> mapB) {

        this.maps = new Pair<>(mapA, mapB);
        this.combinedMaps = new HashMap<>(mapA);

        if (mapB != null) {
            mapB.forEach(combinedMaps::putIfAbsent);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMapA() {
        return maps.getKey();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMapB() {
        return maps.getValue();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getCombinedMap() {
        return combinedMaps;
    }
}
```

Another suggestion would be to generify your class by replacing with `String` and `Object` with generic types `K` and `V`. This will not exactly simplify your class but it will provide modularity as the maps can now hold any types the user designates when instantiating a new `MapManager`.

```
public class MapManager<K, V> {

    private Pair<Map<K, V>, Map<K, V>> maps;
    private Map<K, V> combinedMaps;

    public MapManager(Map<K, V> mapA, Map<K, V> mapB) {

        this.maps = new Pair<>(mapA, mapB);
        this.combinedMaps = new HashMap<>(mapA);

        if (mapB != null) {
            mapB.forEach(combinedMaps::putIfAbsent);
        }
    }

    public Map<K, V> getMapA() {
        return maps.getKey();
    }

    public Map<K, V> getMapB() {
        return maps.getValue();
    }

    public Map<K, V> getCombinedMap() {
        return combinedMaps;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yea the specific example was just an example to illustrate the putIfAbsent part being done in the constructor.  That's really what I want to discuss but it sounds like you're saying it's fine.

Comment: It all depends if you're planing to reuse the map combining. For example if you ever intend to update the maps in the future (which is what I would think a map manager would do at some point) then you would need to update `combinedMaps` map as well. In which case you would need to make it a separate method like you did and call it in `getCombinedMap`.